# Push an object to array, obejct overwritting the previos one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, push

I am trying to push the object resultOBJ to the array resultArray
when the button "Добавить обозначение" is clicked.
first object has been sent well, the data is the same what I am looking for, but when I push another object the second object is rewriting the previous one, the third object  is rewriting the first and the second and so on.
here is my code. Please, tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```js
var color = {red:"#ff0000",purple:"#990099",green:"#33cc33",yellow:"#ffff00",blue:"#0000ff",orange:"#ff8000",pink:"#ff0080",
          skyblue:"#00ffff",black:"#000000",gray:"#808080",brown:"#4d1f00"};

      var diams = ["60","65","68","69","70","75","76","80","81","82","85","90"];

      //show hidden elements
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#addRowDDL").click(function(){
              $("#DDL,#deleteRowDDl,#useIt").fadeIn("slow");
          });
      });

        var resultOBJ=new Object();            
        var resultArray = new Array();
        var finalobj = {} ;  
        var obj = new Object();            
      function addDropDownLists(){
          
          var myObject = $("#htmltoget").children().clone();
          $("#DDL").append(myObject);

          $.each(diams,function(key,value){
              myObject.find(".chooseDiams").append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key)
                .text(value));
          });

          $.each(color,function(key,value){
              myObject.find(".chooseColor").append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key)
                .text(key));
          });

          myObject.find(".chooseColor").change(function(){

              displayColors(this);
          });
          myObject.find(".chooseDiams").change(function(){
              displayDiams(this);
              
          });  

              resultArray.push(obj);

      }//End of addDropDownLists function
 function displayColors(param){
          var colorValues = $(param).val();
          resultOBJ.color=colorValues;
          
      }
 function displayDiams(param){
        var  diamsValues = $(param).val() || [];
        resultOBJ.diams=diamsValues;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="htmltoget" style="display: none;">
<div class="DDL-Con">
    <div class="diams">
        <p>Диаметр</p>
        <select class="chooseDiams" multiple>
          <option selected hidden> Выбрать Диаметр</option>
        </select>        
    </div>
    <div class="color">
        <p>Цвет</p>
        <select class="chooseColor">
          <option selected hidden>Выбрать Цвет</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="addRowDDL" onclick="addDropDownLists()" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Добавить обозначение</button>
 <div id="bigwrapper">
  <div id="DDL">        
  </div>      
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Some of the code appears to be cut off because SO thinks its a html tag in the post.  It can only be seen by clicking edit.

Comment: You should create a new object each time addDropDownLists is called, not only once in global scope,  otherwise you will be reusing and overwriting the original object's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a hard time telling what you're trying to accomplish but you push `obj` which is empty and should be giving you an array of empty objects.

Also, you need to create a new object for each call of `addDropDownLists()` otherwise you are just passing a reference and the changes will effect every object in the array.

```
//show hidden elements
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#addRowDDL").click(function(){
          $("#DDL,#deleteRowDDl,#useIt").fadeIn("slow");
          addDropDownLists();
      });
});

var resultArray = new Array();

  function addDropDownLists(){
      var resultOBJ=new Object(); 

      var myObject = $("#htmltoget").children().clone();
      $("#DDL").append(myObject);

      $.each(diams,function(key,value){
          myObject.find(".chooseDiams").append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key)
            .text(value));
      });

      $.each(color,function(key,value){
          myObject.find(".chooseColor").append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key)
            .text(key));
      });

      myObject.find(".chooseColor").change(function(){
          resultOBJ.color = $(this).val();
      });
      myObject.find(".chooseDiams").change(function(){
          resultOBJ.diams = $(this).val() || [];     
      });  

          resultArray.push(resultOBJ);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
  }//End of addDropDownLists function
```

This setup does insert an empty object into the array the first time the button is clicked, or if there is no change. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish though so I left it as is.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3p37znq1/2/

Comment: It works. Thank you a lot.
If you have an idea how can I delete the last object I have pushed into my array, I am planning to use resultArray.pop(resultOBJ);
Do have any better suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete that empty object in the beginning or actually remove the last object added to `resultArray`?

Comment: the last object added to resultArray, coz the empty object in the beginning is overwritten by the function with the needed values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't push `resultOBJ`, you push `obj` which is always empty as you don't do anything with it after initialization.

When you push `obj` each time you just push a reference to the same instance instead of creating a new one. Any change to `obj` will affect all items in `resultArray`.

In change handler you always update the same instance of `resultOBJ` and this update always overwrites previous change. Actually, the values in this object mean "last selected color anywhere" and "last selected diam anywhere".

Something like this should work:

```
var resultArray = [];
function renderOption(value, name) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = value;
    option.innerHTML = undefined === name ? value : name;
    return option;
}

function updateResult(index) {
    var item = resultArray[index], 
        node = document.querySelector("#DDL").childNodes.item(index);
    item.diam = node.querySelector(".chooseDiams").value;
    item.color = node.querySelector(".chooseColor").value;
}

function addDropDownLists() {

    var container = document.querySelector("#DDL"),
        index = resultArray.length,
        changeHandler = updateResult.bind(null, index),
        tpl = document.querySelector(".DDL-Con"),
        node = tpl.cloneNode(true),
        list, key, len
    ;

    list = node.querySelector(".chooseDiams");
    for (key = 0, len = diams.length; key < len; key++) {
        list.appendChild(renderOption(diams[key]));
    }
    list.onchange = changeHandler;

    list = node.querySelector(".chooseColor");
    for (key in color) {
        list.appendChild(renderOption(key, color[key]));
    }
    list.onchange = changeHandler;

    container.appendChild(node);
    resultArray.push({
        diam: null,
        color: null
    });
    updateResult(index);
}
```

PS: Sorry, I see you use jQuery... I'm too lazy to remember it's API. Haven't used it for a long time. Hope, you'll catch the main idea.

PPS: if you plan to delete items, maybe it's better to bind the whole node and search for it's index via `isSameNode()` method. Bound indexes will become invalid after removing item, they will shift.